# implement inherited abstract member error

Tags: c#, .net

[![ implement inherited abstract member][1]][1]

I know this must be a common error. But I just can't seem to get rid of it, as I am completely new to C#.NET. I get this error while working in the code behind Windows forms. How should I get rid of the error?

Comment: What code is generating the error?

Comment: Going to need more details/code samples

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly without seeing your code, but you have a class somewhere that inherits from a base class that defines abstract members. This means that your class **must** implement those members, or your code won't compile. IntelliSense should give you a hint as to what members need to be implemented.